# Why does fseek from SEEK_CUR use random character for space?

Tags: c, io, fseek

Having this:

```
int main (void) {

    FILE *fp = fopen("txt2", "r+");

    rewind(fp); 
    fprintf(fp, "ab");
    fseek(fp,1L,SEEK_CUR); //trying to change offset to 1,2,3,...
    fprintf(fp, "cd");
    rewind(fp);

    for(int c;(c=getc(fp))!=EOF;)
        putchar(c);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

I want to know, If `fseek` from current position offsets forward with spaces or some garbage. I will gives output with `^` in places, where should be space.

```
fseek(fp,0L,SEEK_CUR)
->  abcd //yes, that is what I expect

fseek(fp,1L,SEEK_CUR)
-> abccd //not space -> 'c' char instead
     ^

fseek(fp,2L,SEEK_CUR)
-> abcdcd //'cd' are in addition (random chars?)
     ^^

fseek(fp,3L,SEEK_CUR)
-> abcdccd //'cdc' no it is probably not "random", they repeat
     ^^^

fseek(fp,100000000000L,SEEK_CUR)
-> abcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcd

fseek(fp,1000000000000000000000000L,SEEK_CUR0
->warning: integer constant is too large for its type
fseek(fp,1000000000000000000000000L,SEEK_CUR);
```

What is going on with fseek moving? They are pattern on which the "moved char" will be made? In this case according to the next `printf` chars? (`cd`). I do not really understand this behaviour and how to move by spaces with fseek? I only know to use `rewind` before and after every writing in order to perform correct read (in for loop), but that does not explain the behaviour. Can someone give a hint?

Comment: You're seeking past the end of the file, which leaves a "hole", and you're expecting the library to use a space character to fill that hole: what makes you think it should?  I've never seen this as part of the contract in the library, and so it's probably getting whatever junk was in the buffer that you just seeked past. I'm almost sure there is no defined behavior here.

Comment: Opening with `r+` and the `fprintf()` calls indicate you want to read and write `txt2`; the 2 `fprintf()` explain the `ab` and `cd` bytes. If not intended, switch to opening with `r` and don't output to `fp`.  To understand questions about space(s), it would help to post the input file.

Comment: @SteveFriedl so how to then make "room" at the end of file, so I can move just before the end and write? (Which was intended from the post)

Comment: @autistic456 I'm not sure I quite get this question - if you want to move to the end of the file, then you use the `SEEK_END` token with an offset of 0.

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I see what's going on. It's not using spaces, it's using NUL bytes, which is much more in line with expectations but not showing up in your output.

In your sample code that shows the output, change it to:

```
    for(int c; (c = getc(fp)) != EOF;)
    {
        if (c == 0) c = '.';  // ADD ME
        putchar(c);
    }
```

Now it will show a dot every time there's a NUL byte, which represents the hole you seeked past.

Starting with an empty `txt2` file and a seek offset of 2, it shows:

```
ab..cd
```

Because you weren't seeing the NUL bytes on your terminal, it made it look like things were all shifted around, and it had me scratching my head for a minute.

**EDIT**: your post would be a lot clearer if you would show the contents of the `txt2` file before-and-after, because these changes are cumulative and impossible to follow when the NUL bytes enter the game.

This should do the trick:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void showfile(FILE *fp, const char *which)
{
    // using | characters to show the start and end of the buffer
    // in case there are trailing blanks involved.
    printf("File %s: |");
    for (int c; (c = getc(fp)) !=EOF;)
    {
        if (c == 0) c = '.';
        putchar(c);
    }
    printf("|\n");
}


int main (void) {

    FILE *fp = fopen("txt2", "r+");

    long offset = 3L;  //trying to change offset to 1,2,3,...
    printf("Running with offset = %ld\n", offset);

    showfile(fp, "before");

    rewind(fp);
    fprintf(fp, "ab");
    fseek(fp, offset, SEEK_CUR);
    fprintf(fp, "cd");
    rewind(fp);

    showfile(fp, "after ");

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Then running it:

```
Running with offset = 2
File before: ||
File after : |ab..cd|

// rerun with previous file
Running with offset = 3
File before: |ab..cd|
File after : |ab..ccd|
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what is actually happening:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("txt2", "r+");   
// need to check (!=NULL) to assure `fopen()` was successful

rewind(fp);      
// `fopen()` places current position in file at beginning, so this call not needed

fprintf(fp, "ab");     
// current position now ==2 (starts at 0)

fseek(fp,1L,SEEK_CUR); //trying to change offset to 1,2,3,...
// current position now at 3 I.E. "ab?"

fprintf(fp, "cd");     
// current position now == 5 I.E. "ab?cd"

the value, at the '?' is what ever happened to be on the disk at (current position =2) position in the file
```